# how to pass a variable in JSON string

Tags: json, google-apps-script

i need to pass a variable instead the token value in json.stringify

i can use the following code in google-apps script to send a token to FCM:

```
function sendtokens() {
  //lets say my variable is:
  var token = ...
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd', {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'key=AAAAB.....LK',
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      to: '/topics/test' ,
      // the following works well:
      registration_tokens: ['dNxYMH....K7O'], 
      // i want to know how to write:
      registration_tokens: [' + token +'],
    })
  });
  Logger.log(response); 
}
```

i want to put the variable of tokens instead of the token itself, i tried to write the variable between quotes "" and between ' ' , none of them works

Comment: Review the fundamentals of how variables and strings work in JavaScript. Then also review array initialization and this arbitrary example: `var a = [1, 2, '3', "4", token, "The variable 'token' has the value: " + token, "The variable 'token' has the value '" + token + "'", String(token), token.toString()]`

Comment: thanks for your answer but please non of them work in google script, maybe i have some mistake, please explain to me how to use it in: registration_tokens: [...]

Comment: didnt work! In order to receive it by the server the token string must be between two '  ' because when i type as it ['dNxYMH....K7O'] it works. thank you TheMaster any other suggestions please

Comment: i tried also ['token'] and then code.gs didn't recognize it as variable.

Comment: yes the var is defined for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As described in this guide: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external
Problem solved using stringify as follow:

```
var data = {
'entry': {
'group': {
  'title': 'Dog Skateboarding',
  'description': 'My dog gets some serious air'
},
'keywords': 'dog, skateboard'
 }
 } 
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
```

THANK you theMaster and tehhowch.